# Div disappearing until I scroll in Opera

Tags: html, css, menu

I'm coding a webpage, and I have a problem with a div disappearing in Opera and Maxthon browsers (works OK with firefox).

The div is a simple menu with a fixed position that slides down with the window scroll, however when clicking a link in it it will scroll down but sometimes it just disappears until i scroll again.

I only use HTML and CSS, i have no knowledge in Javascript or anything, but it's pretty annoying. Is there a way to fix this?

relevant code:

HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#merch">Merchandise</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#menu
    {
        position: fixed;
        margin-left: 5px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        width: 14%;
        height: 100px;
        border: 3px red solid;
        background: white;
        z-index: 100;
}

#menu ul
{
        position: absolute;
        float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting its position with `left` and `top` instead of `margin`.

```
#menu
    {
        position: fixed;
        left: 5px;
        top: 10px;
        width: 14%;
        height: 100px;
        border: 3px red solid;
        background: white;
        z-index: 100;
}
```

---

**update**

I search a bit, and it seems it is a known Opera Bug.

A workaround is to continuously animate some property that does not mess with your layout, but causes the engine to redraw the element. So using CSS animation and targeting the `box-shadow` with an almost non-existent shadow fixes the problem.

```
#menu
{
    position: fixed;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 14%;
    height: 100px;
    border: 3px red solid;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 100;
    -webkit-animation:noop 0.1s infinite; /*fix for maxthon*/
    animation: noop 0.1s infinite; /*fix for opera*/
}

@keyframes noop {/*fix for opera*/
  0%   { box-shadow:0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1); }
  100%   { box-shadow:0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes noop{/*fix for maxthon*/
  0%   { box-shadow:0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1); }
  100%   { box-shadow:0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); }
  }
```

(*in my opera there is a delay before starting the animation so if you start clicking right away, there may be a delay before fixing the issue for the first time..*)

Another solution is to upgrade Opera (*since it is now to **v21***)

Comment: Sadly that didn't work, it still disappears the same

Comment: can you post a live link ? what you describe should no happen, so it might be something else interfering with it..

Comment: Sure, sorry for the delay, needed to upload it

http://wolfpawstudios.zzl.org/test/

Comment: @WolfyD what OS and what browser versions ? It works fine in Windows 7 Opera v12.15 and latest Maxthon..

Comment: Windows 8 Pro x64  -  
Opera 12.15 x64  -  
Maxthon 4.3.2.1000

Comment: Though yeah now that i think of it the 64 bit version of opera might be kinda buggy i guess

Comment: Another thing i noticed is that you have invalid HTML. Run your code and fix those, as it might be the reason you are getting unexpected results.. See the [validation results](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwolfpawstudios.zzl.org%2Ftest%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3+http%3A%2F%2Fvalidator.w3.org%2Fservices)

Comment: Thanks, I'll get on that

Comment: Fixed all errors, both in HTML and CSS, sadly it's still happening, but I'm pretty sure it's just an Opera x64 bug or something. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: @WolfyD updated answer with a workaround to this bug.

Comment: Thank you, I've tried, sadly it still doesn't work. The thing is, iT's not like it doesn't exist when it disappears, it just doesn't draw, when i select it it draws properly, if i move the cursor over it it changes to the pointer so... i doN't really know what'S going on